# Which UML diagrams should I use for this?

Tags: uml

I have some classes (4) that are interacting and I would like to show how, basically what functions calls what and maybe the parameters.

I'd also like to show the flow of some operations, but for that I think activity diagrams would do, or maybe sequence diagrams.

Either way, I'm not sure what to use for the first case.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for [Interaction Diagram](http://atlas.kennesaw.edu/~dbraun/csis4650/A&D/UML_tutorial/interaction.htm) man!

Comment: Or its brother, the Sequence Diagram. A Class diagram as well to support the Sequence diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was posed over 2 years ago, but oh well. Interaction diagrams if you have a lot of iteration. Sequence diagrams if the algorithm is highly sequential.

But for the purpose of doing what you are trying to do (which is basically trying to do a graphical pseudocode representation), I'd opt for interaction diagrams.

Sequence diagrams are typically poor substitutes to pseudo-code as their original intention is to show time dependencies between systems as part of the execution (and completion) of a single task.